# Warning in XML Editor on Typed DataSet ".XSC" File

Tags: xml, ado.net, dataset, xsd, declaration

It all about a typed Dataset...

*The 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource:DataSetUISetting' element is not declared*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<autogenerated>
     This code was generated by a tool.
     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
     the code is regenerated.
</autogenerated>-->
<DataSetUISetting Version="1.00" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
  <TableUISettings>
    <TableUISetting Name="TableName">
      <ColumnUISettings>
        <ColumnUISetting Name="TableColumn">
          <ControlSettings>
            <ControlSetting ArtifactName="Microsoft:System.Windows.Forms:Form">
              <BindableControlInfo Name="LookUpEdit" Type="DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit" AssemblyName="DevExpress.XtraEditors.v9.2, Version=9.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
            </ControlSetting>
          </ControlSettings>
        </ColumnUISetting>
      </ColumnUISettings>
    </TableUISetting>
  </TableUISettings>
</DataSetUISetting>
```

Why do i get this warning in the Dataset.xsc file? If i am not wrong the .xsc file is auto generated by Visual studio. And when i open it with visual studio, i am getting the warning displayed above.

What is the correct way of declaring XML schemas?

Should it be declared correct since it was auto-generated? ;)

Comment: So this is the "So you think you can dance?" of XML questions? Needs a new title.

Comment: This has very little to do with XML, and all to to with datasets (which are not a general XML topic, but are a proprietary MS technology, parts of which use XML). Please retag accordingly.

Comment: As for the question itself,  please explain what exactly you're doing with above XML to get the error - if it's C# code, post it - and what do you actually get (i.e. is it an exception? something else).

Comment: @Pavel: I am not getting an error, i am getting a warning and i don't understand the whole " 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource:DataSetUISetting' element is not declared.

Comment: _Where_ are you getting a warning? What exactly are you doing with the above XML to get a warning? Try to load it into dataset?

Comment: @Pavel: I added the requested info

Comment: Just ignore the warning. Stop looking at it, and you'll stop seeing the warning. The warning is a bug in Microsoft's code, not yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  John Saunders suggested... The warning is a bug in Microsoft's code, not yours

Answer (score 0):

just try and notice the difference between the two of the of the following code, the second one is the right one.

```
 <DataSetUISetting Version="1.00" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-    
     msdatasource">
```

vs

```
 <DataSetUISetting> Version="1.00" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-
    msdatasource">
```

so just copy and replace it with the one u have, the error message will be gone  thank you guys 
this is IDOKO.........

Comment: Are you sure? Looks like the `<>` don't match up.